# Предупреждение с правильным кодом

Tags: php, html, sql, функции

Вывод статей происходит на двух страницах, 1 - превьюшные блоки, что и есть переход на опред. статью, а 2 - конкретная статья, где используется два аргумента.

PHP:

```
function getNews ($limit, $id) {
    global $mysqli;
    connectDB();
    if ($id)
        $where = "WHERE `id` = ".$id;
    $result = $mysqli -> query("SELECT * FROM `news` $where ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT $limit");
    closeDB();
    if (!$id)
        return resultToArray($result);
    else
        return $result->fetch_assoc();
}
```

Обе страницы работают, а предупреждение на той, где используется лишь один аргумент.

**Предупреждение: Warning: Missing argument 2 for getNews(), called in W:\domains\dszorenka\news.php on line 6 and defined in W:\domains\dszorenka\functions\functions.php on line 14**

По сути, как мне кажется, он проверяет до кода функции, а то что внутри нее проверка на существование аргумента - ее не волнует. Может быть действительно неправильный код.

Comment: А не пробовали сначала почитать букварь по PHP? Раздел "функции  / аргументы по умолчанию".

Comment: И правильно не волнует, почему её должно волновать нечто внутри, если вы нарушаете сигнатуру?

Comment: Я на PHP перешел максимум месяц назад, даже стартовую информацию не всю прочитал. В основном причина этому сходство синтаксиса с С#, где есть у меня опыт немного больше)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите сделать необязательный параметр, нужно указать значение по-умолчанию, например, `false`:

```
function getNews ($limit, $id = false) {
...
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Помечу для себя ошибку и постараюсь запомнить подобного рода ситуации)

Comment: @Escaper Наш сайт отличается от социальных сетей. Он помогает решать прикладные задачи. Поэтому мы используем комментарии только по делу — уточнить проблему, дать конструктивную критику или добавить полезную информацию.

Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers